# SQL query selecting between two dates

Tags: sql

I want to select records between two dates - a startDate and endDate (they are date/time format in sql). I have the following sql query but it does not work, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM house 
WHERE startDate >= '2012/02/22 00:00:00' AND endDate <= '2012-02-25 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What about the query isn't working?  Returns an error? Returns too many records? Returns no records?

Comment: Firstly, try not to mix datetime formatting. The safest way to format a date to be understood by SQL is to use something like `'2012-feb-22 00:00:00`, as that way there can be no confusion over the day/month order.

Comment: you're formatting the date once with slashes and once with dashes.

Comment: I think that format is better: '2012-02-25 00:00:00'. Its easier to sort and its default in mysql.

Comment: thank you guys, it was the mistake in format, i changed the '/' into '-' and it works now. many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest converting the dates to a datetime and comparing them as well as keeping the date standard and consistent.  Something like:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM house 
WHERE DATE(startDate) >= DATE('2012-02-22 00:00:00') 
  AND DATE(endDate) <= DATE('2012-02-25 00:00:00')"
```

NOTE: I assumed your startDate and endDate were of the same format as the strings your provided.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want all rows that `startDate` is `'2012-02-22'` or later and `endDate` is `'2012-02-22'` or previous? Then, use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM house 
WHERE startDate >= '2012-02-22' 
  AND endDate < '2012-02-26'           --- notice the `<`, not `<=`
                                       --- and the `day+1`
```

---

When using dates with SQL products, better use this format in queries and statements: `'20120222'` or this (which I find easier to read: `'2012-02-22'`.

Using slashes like `'2012/02/22'` or any other order than `Year-Month-Day` is not recommended.

There's no need to include the time part. `'2012-02-22 00:00:00'` is the same as `'2012-02-22'`.

Using `endDate <= '2012-02-25 00:00:00'` means that any row with date 25nd of Feb. 2012 but time after midnight (`'00:00:00'`) will not match the condition. If you want those rows, too, use `endDate < '2012-02-26'` instead.

You could use `DATE(endDate) <= DATE('2012-02-25 00:00:00')` or `DATE(endDate) <= '2012-02-25'` but these conditions are "un-sargable", so your queries will not be able to use an index on `endDate`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the builtin [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in MySql that takes same format mask as [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
start_date >= str_to_date('2012/02/22 00:00:00','%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats type casting issue the reason why it din work because the input you are matching in the where clause is different that is the column is of date or datetime type and you are matching with a manual string format either use `to_char` on the left side of where to match the format on the right side or use `to_date()` on right side.

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM house 
   WHERE 
    to_char(startDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD
      24hh:mm:ss')>= 
     '2012/02/22  00:00:00' 
         AND to_char(endDate, 
      'YYYY/MM/DD
      24hh:mm:ss') <= '2012-02-25 
        00:00:00'
```