# Select records between two different dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select records from a table that has a date between 28-02-2012 to 30-30-2012

Does any one know how to do this, please answer it

Thanks

i want data like this after run the query

```
proname pc1tot pc2tot  allpctot

sample1  10      12      22
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query selecting between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396798/sql-query-selecting-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date_col BETWEEN '2012-02-28' AND '2012-03-30'
```

I assume this is typo- Not `2012-30-30`, It is `2012-03-30`

Answer (score 1):

Without a table schema, here's the principle:

```
select myDate, other fields...
from myTable
where myDate >= '2012-02-28' and myDate <= '2012-03-30'
```

You can also use "between" in some databases:

```
select myDate, other fields...
from myTable
where myDate between '2012-02-28' and '2012-03-30'
```

Comment: yeah this one work,but it return empty rows ,but this query retrun empty rows. but i want now records for this condition (dd-mm-yy)28-02-2012 to 03-03-2012

Comment: Can you provide sample data that you're selecting from?  Also what data type is the date column?

Comment: i was gave the sample after question

Comment: No, the *source* data - including the date column AND what data type (string, datetime) etc its defined as in the table - it may be easiest to show its "create table" script for that

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from table1 where field_val between 28-02-2012 and 30-30-2012
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to store your dates not in day-month-year format but [format required by mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) - year-month-day.

So, you have to change your table structure.

Comment: You ought to store dates in the appropriate [date / time data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html)

Comment: thanks for the link. Feel free add it right to the answer, not comment.

Answer (score -1):

There are similar answers for your question.

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '28-02-2012' AND '30-02-2012'

Comment: yeah this one work, but i want now records for this condition (dd-mm-yy)28-02-2012 to 03-03-2012

Comment: All examples here should work. But what is now record that you are referring to?